# Is there a shorthand notation to $frac(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor $?

Tags: notation

In old Hewlet Packard calculators, it was common to have an int and a frac function, which were giving the integer and the fraction part of a number.

Nowadays, the floor function is quite common and noted $ \lfloor x \rfloor $ but to get fraction part, you usually need to compute it "by hand" by explicitly writing something like `x - floor(x)`. I wondered if there existed some mathematical short hand notation for $frac(x) =  x - \lfloor x \rfloor $.

Thank you.

Comment: Most common is $\{x\}$.

Comment: Thank you but why wouldn't you post this as a reply (which I could accept as the reply) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested in the comments:

The standard notation for the fractional part of $x$ is $\{x\}$.